# How to create anchor link to each array inside while loop

Tags: php

I want to display contents  when I click the title value. 
The code shown below displays several titles, so if I click on one of them I want to display the contents in it.

```
<ul class="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($page) ) {
?>

<li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">

<?php
echo $row['title'];

}?>
```

Comment: its only tagged as `php`. you can do that with some client side scripts. use javascript. and in your looping create a hidden container inside is the content you want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">        
    <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($page) ) {
    ?>        
       <li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
          <a href="">        
             <?php
                echo $row['title'];
             ?>
          </a>
       </li>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul class="" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($page) ) {
?>

<li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">

<?php
echo $row['title'];
?>
 </a></li>
<?php
}?>
```